# dataLayer: get arrays objects with specific value

Tags: javascript, google-datalayer

I have a simple JS script that may count values from `"price"` from each product if the `"brand"` is equal to `"Krups"`.

Now I am stuck on finding these objects in the data layer which have brand equals to `"Krups"`.

I'm getting errors and can't get objects with products in brand Krupms.

Is there any option how I can get into the array of all objects which have key `"brand"` equal to `"Krups"`?

**My dataLayer:**

[image]

**My Script:**

```
function getFromDataLayer(key) { 
    let result = null; 
    dataLayer.push(function() { 
        let value = this.get(key);
        if (value) {
            result = value;
        }
    });
    return result;    
};
    
const ecom = getFromDataLayer('ecommerce')

if (ecom.filter(function(e) { return e.brand === 'Krups'; }).length > 0) {
  console.log(this)
}
```

Comment: `dataLayer` is an array of object, isn't it? You can simply cycle through all elements of this array and filter out entries required for your work.

Comment: @koloml, how can I do that?

Comment: If it's actually a Google Analytics (or Universal Analytics) `dataLayer` then you can simply use good old [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Because it's just an array with custom `push` method injected by tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
if (ecom?.purchase?.products?.filter(function(e) { return e.brand === 'Krumps'; }).length > 0) {
  console.log(this)
}
```